# Accessing Content Item Throwing Server Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am using Sitecore 6.5 and facing an issue here. We have 3 servers: **Dev, QA, Staging**.

I have created a User Role specifically to only publish the content items. This user role is a member of:

- Sitecore Client Publishing
- Sitecore Client Authoring

Everything work **fine** in the **Dev** and **QA** box. When I am doing the same thing in the **Staging** and clicking to any content item under (sitecore\Content\Home\ContentItem1) Sitecore is throwing me **server error** like this:

[image: Error]

I also tried to look up Log files in Staging, but its not getting updated (don't know why). Also asked for IIS Log files, but don't know what to look for in that.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Any advice/help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try setting `<customErrors mode="off" />` in web.config and then looking at the stacktrace? It will  be impossible to guess without more info.

Comment: The thing is Staging is managed by server admin guys, and I dont have access to it. But let me give a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you can ask for Sitecore logs from Data/logs folder - more likely you will find the exception there

Comment: Technically, you don't have to have access to the server - just go to Sitecore->Development Tools->File Explorer. Download the web.config, make your change, upload it the same way. (assuming Sitecore runs on your staging environment of course)

Comment: @All: I dont know what was going in the back end, but seems like creating a separate user with the same roles (Sitecore Client Publishing, Sitecore Client Authoring) solved the problem. Crazy Sitecore. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried to look up Log files in Staging, but its not getting updated

That's really strange. Could it be that you are looking in the wrong location?
If you have access to Desktop mode you can try Sitecore-> App Applications -> Log Viewer

By the way- what do you mean by "staging"? Is this Staging module or Content Delivery instance?

Comment: I asked the Admin person and he gave me the log file which is the same what I am viewing through sitecore UI. Its dated back to 6/13/13. Same file I am viewing under the Reporting Tools\Log Viewer.

Comment: "We have 3 servers: Dev, QA, Staging." - In this context I would take it to mean Staging CD instance

Comment: I haven't thought that it's possible to disable Sitecore's logging. Could you hit /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and check setting "LogFolder"

Comment: @All: I dont know what was going in the back end, but seems like creating a separate user with the same roles (Sitecore Client Publishing, Sitecore Client Authoring) solved the problem. Crazy Sitecore. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

@All: I dont know what was going in the back end, but seems like creating a totally separate user with the same roles (Sitecore Client Publishing, Sitecore Client Authoring) solved the problem. Crazy Sitecore. LOL! –